Find the minimum value of 2 types of relationship group
There are $20$ students in a class. We define that if a group has 3 students who know each other will be called a "good" group and a group has 3 students who do not know each other will be called a "bad" group. Put $S$ is the number of "good" and "bad" group. Find the minimum value of $S$.
Here is my solution and I don't know if it is true:
Among $20$ students there are $\displaystyle\binom{20}{3}$ ways to choose a group has $3$ students
We will fix a student $a_i, i = \overline{1,20}$
For the student $a_i$, devide the class into $2$ separated group $A$ and $B$
Group $A$ is the set which includes students who know student $a_i$
Group $B$ is the set which includes students who do not know student $a_i$
Besides, we have $|A| + |B| = 19$, thus
$$|A|.|B| \leq 90$$
And $|A|.|B|$ is the number of group has $3$ students which does not satisfy
On the other hand, we have $\displaystyle S= \binom{20}{3} - \dfrac{20.|A|.|B|}{3}$
Because we will make $i$ run from $1$ to $20$ then for a group which does not satisfy $a_m,a_n,a_p$ will calculate it $3$ times when we make this calculation $20.|A|.|B|$ so it must divide $3$ to avoid duplicating
Then $$S \ge \binom{20}{3} - \dfrac{20.90}{3} = 540$$

Note: It is not true that $ S = { 20 \choose 3 } - 20 AB /3$.

You want OEIS A014557. There are links to proofs of the result. $\quad$ Your approach of counting the number of red/blue edges at a vertex is good, but you'd have to refine it further.

For each vertex, let $r_i$ (resp $b_i)$ denote the red (resp blue) degree of the vertex, namely the number of red (resp blue) edges containing that vertex.
Clearly, $ r_i + b_i = 19$.
We count the number of red-blue pairs of edges at each of these 20 vertices.
Clearly there are  $ \sum r_i b_i$ such pairs.
Let $R$ be the number of red chromatic triangles, $B$ be the number of blue chromatic triangles, and $T$ be the number of non-chromatic triangles.
We want to find $ \min (R+B)$.
Clearly  $R+B+T = { 20 \choose 3 }$.
Clearly, only the non-chromatic triangles contribute red-blue pairs, and each contribute exactly 2, thus $ 2T = \sum r_i b_i   $.
Since $r_ib_i \leq 9 \times 10$, so $ T \leq 20 \times 9 \times 10/2 = 900$, and $ R+B \geq {20 \choose 3 } - 900 = 240$.
It remains to find such a coloring that yields $T = 240$. Instead of manually trying to construct such an example and count the number of chromatic triangles, observe that the above shows that if $r_i \in \{ 9, 10 \} \, \forall i$, then $T = 900$ and $ R+B = 240$.
It is obvious that such a coloring exists. (See notes for a hint.)
Notes

We also have $ 3R + 3B + T = \sum { r_i \choose 2 } + { b_i \choose 2 } $, but we do not need to use it in this proof.
The general case can be done in a similar manner. You do have to track the parity to properly bound $T$.
Hint for a possible construction: There is an obvious/natural construction for each vertex to have a  red-degree of 9.


Can you recommend for me some graph book for olympiad? Thanks
